# Is it possible to use experimental version of React while using Create React App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I would like to test React concurrent mode, and still using create-react-app?
Is it possible?

I have check create-react-app documentation, and also looks for a specified NPM module, and didn't found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the short answer is *yes*. All you have to do is to create your new app with CRA like this:

```
npx create-react-app myapp
```

Then, after the main installation was completed. You can simply enable the **Concurrent Mode (Experimental)** by adding it to your project *(You have to make sure the current version of react is supporting this experimental mode)*:

```
npm install react@experimental react-dom@experimental

# or:

yarn add react@experimental react-dom@experimental
```

Then simply, you can change the `index.js` root element with replacing `ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootEl)` with:

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootEl)
root.render(<App />)
```

**NOTE:** You can [learn more about how to enable this feature properly](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-enable-react-concurrent-mode).